# Ember How fire observes when create object(observe was set already in model)

Tags: ember.js, observers

I cannot fire observes function when was created object in Controller Array

My code:

Model

```
App.Meeting = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    type: null,
    proposes: null
 });
App.Meeting.reopen({
    proposedChanged: function() {
       //some do
    }.observes('proposes')
});
```

Controller

```
App.meetingsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    loadList: function(){
        var me = this;
        $.getJSON(url,function(data){

            if(data.status == 0){
                $(data.meetings).each(function(index,value){
                    var m = App.Meeting.create(value)
                    me.pushObject(m);    
                });

            }else{
                alert('Error loading content');
            }               
        });
    },

});

App.meetingsController.loadList();
```

When i run application Controller has get JSON data and created App.Meeting with that data, but observer not fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was creating a jsbin to play with @Darshan Sawardekar got it right, so now you have to answers to play with :)

The important code:

```
App.meetingsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  loadList: function(){
    var me = this;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
      if(data.status == 0){
        $(data.meetings).each(function(index, value){
          var m = App.Meeting.create();
          m.set('id', value.id);
          m.set('name', value.name);
          m.set('type', value.type);
          m.set('proposes', value.proposes);

          me.pushObject(m);
        });
      } else {
         alert('Error loading content');
      }               
    });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

See here for a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ejadax/6/edit) that shows the concept.

Comment: Have an upboat from me too!

Comment: @ST_5 see my edit, I've added a jsbin where only `.set(...)` is used and it's working, have a look

Comment: Oh, sorry @ntuitivepixel you way is correct worked. Thanks
PS: At first i lost remove value when created model(i mean that place var m = App.Meeting.create(value); - its not correct). Thank again.

Answer (score 1):

I think observers fire when you do `meeting.set('proposes', 'value')`. They don't fire inside a `create` call. You could modify your create to retouch proposes. This might work,

```
var m = App.Meeting.create(value);
m.set('proposes', value.proposes);
```

Comment: straight to the point, this deserves an upvote :) but couldn't resist to also post an answer :)